# Proof that the sum does not depend on enumeration ...

Tags: probability

I've come across the following basic lemma in a basic probability book, and I can't seem to understand why the provided argument is enough to prove it.

Lemma: Let $I$ be a countably infinite set and let $\lambda_i \geq 0$ for all $i \in I$. Then for any two enumerations of $I$: $i_1,i_2,\dots$ and $j_1,j_2,\dots$ we have 
$\sum_n \lambda_{i_n} = \sum_n \lambda_{j_n}$.

Proof: Fix $N \in \mathbb N$. We can find $N\leq M \leq N'$ such that $\{i_1,\dots,i_N\} \subseteq \{j_1,\dots,j_M\} \subseteq \{i_1,\dots,i_{N'}\}$ and noting that $\sum_{n=1}^N\lambda_{i_n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^M \lambda_{j_n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N'} \lambda_{i_n}$. The result follows from letting $N \rightarrow \infty$.

I'm wondering why letting $N \rightarrow \infty$ is enough to prove the statement?

Comment: Here is an informal intuitive explanation. Assuming that the sums converge to some limit, then the difference in the $i$ sums is bounded by any $\epsilon$ we like, above a certain $N$. But we can "sandwich" the $j$ sums between them. So it's also bounded. EDIT: Also the restriction of $\lambda_i \geq 0$ should mean the convergence is absolute, so switching terms doesn't matter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence.

Comment: The first inclusion is sort of enough, because it shows that the sup (finite or infinite)  of the partial sums of the first sequence is $\le $ the sup of the partial sums of the second. Symmetry gives the inequality the other way.

Comment: So, the informal pinching theorem argument would hold if $I$ was an open interval no? Here it's a countable infinite set. Also, we haven't forced $\lambda_i < \infty$ to make sure that these sums have limits. Am I missing something real obvious here?

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake in assuming convergence to a finite value. I guess it's more subtle than that. Still, I suppose you could keep applying that argument an infinite number of times, to get an infinite number of inclusions, alternating between $i$ and $j$?

Comment: The argument only works for $I$ a countable set, we have used in a fundamental way the definition of "sum of a sequence" as the limit of the partial sums.

Comment: What would fail if $I$ were not countable?

Comment: it would not be a sum but needs to be an integral. the statement would be some kind of transformation formula.